# Table-per-hierarchy (TPH) inheritance with Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2012

I have the following base (abstract model):

```
public abstract class StatusMessage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Message
    /// </summary>
    /// [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

    public int UseraccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Useraccount Useraccount { get; set; }
}
```

And this model is derived from StatusMessage:

```
public class ProjectStatusMessage : StatusMessage
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

In my context I built a StatusMessage set:

```
public IDbSet<StatusMessage> StatusMessage { get; set; }
```

In my initializer I try to build a new project status message and save it to the database:

```
var statusMessages = new List<StatusMessage>
{
    new ProjectStatusMessage
    {
        Description = "Test-Project-Status-Message",
        ProjectId = 1,
        UseraccountId = 1
    }                   
};
statusMessages.ForEach(s => context.StatusMessage.Add(s));
context.SaveChanges();
```

When the code is executed the compiler throws an exception.
There's a conflict with the insert and the foreign key constraint in 'ProjectStatusMessage_Project'. Conflict is in table 'dbo.Project', column 'Id'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem on my own.
The order in my initializer was wrong.
I created the projectstatus first, then the project...